# When marking a door hinge mortise, how far from the edge does the hinge go? New construction, interior door

Tags: doors, hinges

How far from the edge of the door face should the hinge go? Please use the image below to see what my question means.

Here are all the details:

- The door slab thickness is 1 3/8"
- The hinge leaf's height is 3 1/2"
- The hinge leaf's width is 1 1/2" (not including the knuckles)
- The hinge opened up all the way is 3 1/2" wide total

As far as I can tell, all the materials and parts I'm using are standard. This is a new construction, interior door.

I've Googled this for a long time, and I'm not getting any info (I'm only getting stuff like how far down from the top of the door, etc.). I've read things about putting the hinge in place on the door, flush, and tracing it, but that is confusing to me (which area would be flush, the leaf face? Or if the edge of the leaf was flush to the inside face of the door, then the hinge would stick out too far to the outside face, by 1/8".).

This image isn't my actual door, I'm just using it so you can see the dimension that I mean.

Please let me know if you need anymore info.

Please see the image below:

[image: Mortise distance from edge]

Comment: It’s less common these days, but some doors come with beveled edges. Be sure to have the barrel of the hinge on the wide face of the door.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My factory hung 1 3/8" doors have 3/16" of door beyond the hinge mortise. This is not so important and can vary a little bit. More important is the relation to the jamb side hinge mortise so the door closes and seats fully. If your jamb is already mortised then you will want to match that with your door mortise. There must be a little space (1/16" or so) between the closed door and the hinge side door stop to allow for the swinging of the door and any finishes you may be applying.

Again, the relation of the door hinge mortise and the jamb side hinge mortise are what you will want to pay attention to.

Comment: +1 for the reminder to leave a gap between the stop and the hinge side of the door.